# не работает телеграм бот (aiogram) Код успешно выполняется и всё, хотя должен ещё работать дальше, пока я его не отключу

Tags: python, telegram

```
from aiogram import *
from config import photo_url

token = 'TOKEN'
bot = Bot(token=token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    chat_id = message.from_user.id
    await message.reply('текст')
    await dp.bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=photo_url)

executor.start_polling(dp,skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Вы бы токен не показывали

Comment: как вы его запускаете? как проверяете? проблем в вашем коде нет, он полностью рабочий

Comment: вообщем такая штука. Я запускал через pycharm, но решил попробовать через обычную IDLE. И знаете что? Оно сработало! То ли проблема в pycharme (хоть ранее я запускал, всё было окей) То ли во мне. Я не знаю.

Comment: А на токен похер. Всё равно тот аккаунт через который я делал бота с этим токеном вроде как забанили. Извиняюсь за тавтологию